# Having issues with .php files and the GAE

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, configuration, yaml

I am trying to get a contact form to work on my GAE.  I have the app.yaml complete and it's working for everything bar the .php files it shows a `No web page was found for the web address` when you try to go onto the webpage.  The files are all in the correct directory.  I originally had the form as form.php but when deploying it showed: `WARNING: The URL path "/form" is reserved and will not be matched.` So I changed it contact.php, but it's still showing the same error.  Would you guys have any recommendations on what I should try?  The contact.php has the form in it and I also have contact_control.php to do form validation and send the email.

Thanks!

```
#service: default
service: test-landing
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: assets/\1
  secure: always

- url: /home
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always

- url: /news
  static_files: www/news.html
  upload: www/news.html
  secure: always

- url: /terms
  static_files: www/terms.html
  upload: www/terms/news.html
  secure: always

- url: /privacy
  static_files: www/privacy.html
  upload: www/privacy.html
  secure: always

- url: /faq
  static_files: www/faq.html
  upload: www/faq.html
  secure: always

- url: /contact
  script: /contact.php
  secure: always
- url: /contact
  static_files: /contact.php
  upload: /contact.php
  secure: always

- url: /contact_control
  script: www/contact_control.php
  secure: always

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will need to configure your app.yaml to recognize and use the PHP files on your Google App Engine.

I would recommend you to take a look at the following documentation on how to configure your app.yaml to work with PHP.

- [Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)
- [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref)

Besides that, there is the following documentation, on how to configure your App Engine to work correctly with PHP, that I would recommend you to take a look - they are actually quickstart documentation, which seems to be the exact place where you are. :)

- [Quickstart for PHP in the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart)
- [Quickstart for PHP 7 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart)

Let me know if the information helped you!